# Raw touch/swipe data in Flutter? Compared to Java w/ Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, swipe-gesture, raw-data

I am very new to flutter development, and I have to make a fairly quick decision on whether or not it is the right platform for my internship project.

I have to create an interface which requires all directional swipes to navigate to different menus (I'm thinking of doing nested horizontal and vertical scrolling, which I have had trouble with in Android Studio) -  but more importantly, I have to save the raw data from the touching/tapping/swiping. I can't just save "left swipe" or "right swipe", I also have to know pressure, velocity, location, exact path, etc.

Is this feasible in flutter? How does flutter handle this raw data as opposed to Android studio? Does flutter only determine the approximate direction of the swipe and that's it?

I have tried searching for answers all day, but I must be missing some key word, because I have been unable to find the answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html#constructors) is a very extensive `Widget` in this regard. It has *all the capabilities* you are searching for. A simpler version of it, which also has Material design built in, is [`InkWell`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html), but this might be lacking some of the functionality you are searching for.

With a `GestureDetector` wrapped about your `Widget` you will be able to catch all hit events (you can even specify [`HitTestBehavior`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html) (with the `behavior` parameter).

For your custom interactions there are plenty of callbacks implemented. I linked you to [the constructor](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html#constructors), which contains a bunch of useful parameters, like `onTapDown`/`Up`, `onVertical`/`HorizontalDragStart`/`Update`/`End`.

This is not even everything, but using those you can programatically define your behavior. Let me explain the concept with a small example:

```
Offset start;

void verticalDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
  // process the start by working with the details
  start = details.globalPosition;
  // ...
}

void verticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
  // apply your logic
  Offset delta = details.delta;
  // ...
}

// use DragEnd, also for horizontal, pan etc.

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDectector(
  onVerticalDragStart: verticalDragStart,
  // ...
);
```

I hope that you can imagine all the possibilties this *enables*. You can also combine different callbacks. Just take a look at the [parameters in the documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html#constructors) and experiment with what fits for you.

I think that *this is* the **raw data** you asked for.

Comment: GestureDetector looks great for detecting certain gestures, though I can't quite find if it gives me what I need. So with your example, It defines a start position for the tap, and then calculates the delta from that original position on each drag update? What is output at the end - a linear vector from the start position to the end position, or the entire path (even if the user curved along the way)?

Comment: The [`DragUpdateDetails`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html) in the [`GestureDragUpdateCallback`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/GestureDragUpdateCallback.html) for all update callbacks, i.e. vertical, horizontal, pan etc., contain the `globalPosition` as well. The position is an `Offset`, [here all operators you can use to work with them](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html#operators). [`DragEndDetails`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/DragEndDetails-class.html) contain velocity. You will need to combine callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the raw touch movements using `Listener`. The following example shows how to grab a list of points. It uses them to draw the line you just traced with your finger. You can't tell the pressure, but can tell the exact path and velocity (if you stored time with each point). The higher level detector, `GestureDetector`, hides these raw movements from you, but interprets them into the traditional swipes.

(Notes about the example... `shouldRepaint` should be smarter, points returned by Listener are in global co-ordinates so may need to be converted to local (this simple example works because there's no AppBar))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Gesture',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Offset> points = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Listener(
        onPointerDown: (e) {
          points = [];
          points.add(e.position);
        },
        onPointerMove: (e) {
          points.add(e.position);
        },
        onPointerUp: (e) {
          points.add(e.position);
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: new CustomPaint(
          painter: new PathPainter(points),
          child: new Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 300.0,
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points;
  Path path = new Path();

  PathPainter(this.points) {
    if (points.isEmpty) return;
    Offset origin = points[0];
    path.moveTo(origin.dx, origin.dy);
    for (Offset o in points) {
      path.lineTo(o.dx, o.dy);
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawPath(
      path,
      new Paint()
        ..color = Colors.orange
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = 4.0,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true; // todo - determine if the path has changed
  }
}
```

Comment: You say that `GestureDetector` hides them, but they are only **grouped** into *different callbacks*, which is way more **accessible**.

Comment: Exactly, most of us will use `GestureDetector` 99% of the time, but the OP specifically asks for the "exact path, not just left/right", which requires Listener. He/she will presumably use this raw data for some specific purpose alluded to in the question.

Comment: The callbacks actually contain the same position information that the listener provides, i.e. `globalPosition` and not relative to the `Widget`. Summarizing you can say that there are only advantages in using `GestureDetector` because of the grouping and because it **is** the *Flutter way* as it is a `Widget`. It has all information, just already partially processed in forms of grouping into categories, but you can still access **all data** from the callbacks.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I need it for a specific purpose. Without saying too much, I need to plug this data into a back-end created by the company I work for, which will analyze it. Would GestureDetector or Listener be more useful for this? I also can not find anything related to pressure in the documentation - is this feasible as well?

Comment: It's honestly up to you. They do slightly different things. Listener allows you to track the finger (just down, move, up), GestureDetector also interprets the movement into, well, gestures! For example was that "down, slight movement, up" a drag or a tap - in other words was the movement big enough to mean drag or did the finger just slip a bit when tapping. If your back-end is going to do the interpretation, and is happy with down/move/up use Listener. If you need to know whether it was a tap or a swipe, then GD is better. Try both.